# Batch script creates one file and doesn't create anymore?

Tags: batch-file

Here I have an issue where I intend for an existing file called get_tables_to_drop to create a drop_tables.log file, which it does however it doesn't create the drop_tables_final.sql unless I reopen the same script without closing it

```
sqlplus system/system @get_tables_to_drop.sql > drop_tables.log

findstr "drop table pTable" drop_tables.log >>drop_tables_final.sql
```

Comment: maybe a timing problem? Add a `timeout 2` between.

Comment: maybe put `exit` command at the end of your get_tables_to_drop.sql?

Comment: Run those exact commands from a cmd prompt.  Does it produce any errors when running either of the commands? I am hoping there is. I am a bit confused on why you are not using `drop_tables.log` with your `findstr` command.  Shouldn't you be searching that file instead of `drop_reg_tables.log`? I know nothing about sql.

Comment: Hi guys, I can confirm adding a timeout didn't work, my apologies in regards to the code confusion, I renamed the tables and just confused myself.
And I'm not sure where I should be putting the exit? Wherever I've put it after the sql line it hasn't changed anything, any further suggestions guys?